# Change QScrollBar arrows By displaying a picture

Tags: qt

I'm trying to replace the default arrows of QScrollBar with custom arrows that I have as pictures. I tried something but it didn't work out as it's not displaying anything at all...
What I've tried:

```
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    image: url(:/DownArrow.png);
}
```

Comment: Try to explore [the example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar) from documentation. [Style sheets reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets) also might help.

Comment: That doesn't include displaying arrow picture but how to create one in a simple way

Comment: I managed to do what you want with style sheets, but it is very fragile. In order to apply an image to `QScrollBar::sub(add)-line:horizontal(vertical)` you need to provide any non-empty style sheet for `QScrollBar`. Otherwise it doesn't work. And it is fragile because if you try to add any other property into `QScrollBar::sub(add)-line:horizontal(vertical)` style sheet, it goes to default(like no style sheet) for me...